# Download Desktop Ubuntu- Corrupted File Warning?

Tags: windows

I am new to open source OS, and I am trying to install Ubuntu. I've heard it's pretty user-friendly and is a good OS in general. I searched for a while on different OS, and this was the one I wanted in replacement to Windows 8, as it is slow and altogether confusing and crappy. When I saved the Ubuntu file to start installation I waited for the save and when it was finished I opened it. When I tried to open it a warning popped up telling me **Corrupted File**. I was wondering if this was Windows trying to stop me from getting a new OS, there were missing pieces because the save was interrupted, or just a common error and I may have to try again.

Thanks, *That guy who wants to get an open source OS yet is entirely new to it and just wants to replace the crap that is Windows 8 on his computer*

Answer (score 0):

What you downloaded should have been a disk image file called an ISO, with .iso extension. This is not a program you can execute. You need to load ubuntu on to your machine from a cd, which you create using the .iso file you downloaded. I do not know how to burn an ISO from Windows 8 (i don't like it either!) but its very easy from Windows 7, so I assume its not much different in W8. Google for "burn an iso file windows 8" and follow the instructions. You are going to want to keep this CD, as its also your recovery media, and has some very useful utilities as well.

When you have burned the .iso, which is not the same as copying the file onto the CD, you need to put it in your CD drive, and reboot your machine. Most PC's will attempt to boot from it automatically. At this point, ubuntu boots from the CD, has a look at your system, and asks you what you want to do. Some PC's will not automatically boot from the CD, and need to have the boot order changed in the BIOS, which is also pretty easy, but subject of a different question.

If you do not have a CD burner, this can also be done from a USB key, but either way, you need to make a bootable disk or key, not install from Windows.